# Pass an object to a function using format + exec (in Python)

Tags: python

I am writing a two-player RPG game with command line input. It's theoretically easy to write something like this:

```
if input == "advance":
    self.rules.advance( p1, p2 )
elif input == "retreat":
    self.rules.retreat( p1, p2 )
```

But I tried to use `format()` to produce a more elegant and versatile system, and it isn't quite working. Here is the relevant code.

```
def oneTurn(self, actor, target):
    print(actor.name + "'s turn:")
    self.valid = False
    while self.valid == False:
        self.choice = raw_input(":: ")
        if self.choice.upper() in self.rules.verb_list:
            cmd = "self.rules.{0}( {1}, {2} )" 
            cmd = cmd.format( self.choice.lower(), actor, target )
            exec(cmd)
        else:
            print("Unknown command.")
```

Because the game is two player, all actions need to be reversible. That means they accept as arguments both an actor and a target, which will be either p1 or p2. So a full round would be:

```
oneTurn(p1, p2)
oneTurn(p2, p1)
```

But running the program produces a syntax error:

```
self.rules.advance( <__main__.soul instance at 0xblahblahblah>,<__main__.you get the idea> )
```

And the little arrow is pointing at the first "<".

SO: is it possible to use format+exec to pass objects to a function?

Comment: Clearly you haven't defined a `__repr__` suitable for recreating a `soul` object from a string.

Comment: Recreating the object won't be useful, I need to reference the original.

Comment: This seems like a very unwise approach; Daniel's suggestion is much better, or you could consider an explicit dictionary `{command_name: appropriate method}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use getattr, instead of your error prone exec:

```
if self.choice.upper() in self.rules.verb_list:
    cmd = getattr(self.rules, self.choice.lower())
    cmd(actor, target)
else:
    print("Unknown command.")
```

Comment: I just tested this solution. It works perfectly, thank you very much. (This is a great language.)